# Wordpress automatically scales up images

Tags: html, wordpress

I apologize in advance for asking such a simple question but I can't find out what I'm doing wrong.

My company's website is built on wordpress and I am trying to upload a 200x140 size image to a page but the photo is scaling up and covering the entire page. I've checked the dimensions of the image in question and checked the html which has the width and height correct as well.

```
<img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-11515" src="http://www.pablove.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/internships_job.png" alt="internships_job" width="200" height="140"/>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to post code here, otherwise no one can help you

Comment: What is `.size-full`? To me it's like you enable the option by yourself. Don't blame WordPress.

Comment: Inspect the image using your browser's Developer Tools to see what CSS is applied to it. In Chrome, you can open the developer tools by pressing F12. In Opera, you can open it by pressing Ctrl+i. Once you do, try adding a screenshot here of what you found so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the enlarged image due to the styling being applied.

CSS width / height properties will override the width and height attributes on the image tag.

Unfortunately there's not enough information in your question to propose a solution beyong adding `style="width: auto; height: auto;` to your `img` tag.

Look at the CSS being applied to the image and override as appropriate.